# Making a list copy over the contents through appending, rather than containing a reference

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

To start off, this is the code I wanted to use to present my problem in a simplified way, but turns out it actually works as I initially expected the thing to work:

```
list_a = []
list_b = []
for i in range(2):
    list_a = [i, i+1]
    list_b.append(list_a)
```

Now `list_b` is `[[0, 1], [1, 2]]`, as I want it to be.

I'm trying to learn programming by making a simple Tetris clone with pygame, and I wanted to use a similar approach to parse a text file into a list containing rotations/frames of a single block (2d lists). I fill out a 2d `frame`, append it to `frames` which is the list of all frames, and then reuse `frame`. However, unlike in the above example, it seems that when `frame` is appended to `frames`, it's not the contents of `frame`, but a reference to `frame` (though that's probably not the correct term?). What is different about this that it behaves differently, and how do I make it work? Thanks in advance!

```
class Block:

    object = {}

    def __init__(self, block_type):      
        frame = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
        frames = []
        frames_file = open('files\\%s.txt' % block_type, 'r')

        for i, line in enumerate(frames_file):
            if line.strip() == '----':
                frames.append(frame)
                print(frame)
                print(frames)
                print('Append!\n')

            else:
                for x, char in enumerate(line.strip()):
                    y = i % 5
                    if char == '#':
                        frame[x][y] = 1
                    elif char == '.':
                        frame[x][y] = 0

        self.frame = frames

Block.object['T'] = Block('T')
```

Now all `frame`s contain the same thing:

```
>>> Block.object['T'].frame[0] == Block.object['T'].frame[1]
True
```

Just for the record, `files\T.txt` is:

```
....
###.
.#..
....
----
.#..
##..
.#..
....
----
.#..
###.
....
....
----
.#..
.##.
.#..
....
----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around and a helpful (although incomplete) hint from a user who already deleted his answer, this is essentially a duplicate of [Copying 2D lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-2d-lists-in-python)

The problem here was twofold:

1. `frames.append(frame)` indeed only references `frame` in `frames`, I didn't attempt to copy it at any point
2. `frames.append(frame[:]` and `frames.append(list(frame))`, which are the usual ways to copy a list, don't work for nested lists in that form

The proper code is: `frames.append(list(list(i) for i in frame))`