# Changing the value of a copy also changes the value of the original

Tags: python, list, variables, copy

Changing the value of a variable b, which is a copy of a, also changes the value of a.

```
a = [[0]]
b = a.copy()

print("a before", a)

b[0][0] = 1

print("a after ", a)
```

prints:

```
a before [[0]]
a after  [[1]]
```

Although this works:

```
a = [0]
b = a.copy()

print("a before", a)

b[0] = 1

print("a after ", a)
```

prints:

```
a before [[0]]
a after  [[0]]
```

Comment: a copy is only a shallow copy, the "outermost" container was created from scratch, but the items inside are still references. use `from copy import deepcopy`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying nested lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out copy.deepcopy works.

```
import copy

a = [[0]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)

print("a before", a)

b[0][0] = 1

print("a after ", a)
```

prints:

```
a before [[0]]
a after  [[0]]
```