# Comparison of Lists for the 2048 game

Tags: list, function, comparison, mutable

```
def helper(mat):
    for row in mat:
        zero_list = []
        for subrow in row:
            if subrow == 0:
                row.remove(0)
                zero_list.append(0)
        row.extend(zero_list)
    return mat


def merge_left(mat):
    result = mat.copy()
    helper(mat)
    counter = 0 
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        current_tile = 0
        for j in range(len(mat)):
            if mat[i][j] == current_tile:
                mat[i][j-1] *= 2
                mat[i][j] = 0
                counter += mat[i][j-1]
            current_tile = mat[i][j]
    helper(mat)
    return result == mat

print(merge_left([[2, 2, 0, 2], [4, 0, 0, 0], [4, 8, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 2]]))
```

Hey guys,

The result I get for merge_left in the above code is True for the test case.
Given that result is a duplicate copy of mat.
How is it so that result has also been altered in a similar way to mat through this code?
I'd understand this to be the case if I had written

```
result = mat instead of result = mat.copy()
```

Why is this the case? I'm aiming to compare the two states of the input mat. Before the code alters mat and after it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying nested lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`list.copy()` only clones the outer list. The inner lists are still aliases, so modifying one of them modifies `result` and `mat`. Here's a minimal reproduction of the problem:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2]]
>>> y = x.copy()
>>> y[0][0] += 1
>>> y
[[2, 2]]
>>> x
[[2, 2]]
```

You can use `[row[:] for row in mat]` to deep copy each row within the matrix. Slicing and `copy` are pretty much the same.

You can also use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), but it's overkill for this.

Also, `row.remove(0)` while iterating over `row`, as with iterating over any list while adding or removing elements from it, is very likely a bug. Consider a redesign or use `for subrow in row[:]:` at minimum.