# Elementary array identity issue

Tags: python

```
array1=[[0 for rows in range(9)] for cols in range(9)]
array2=list(array1)
array1[0][0]=1
print(array2[0][0])
print(id(array1) is id(array2))
```

This gives:
1
False

The arrays have separate ID's but nevertheless, changing array1 still changes array2.  Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying nested lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

`list()` will only copy the first dimension of your list. But you have a list of lists and the second dimension will still be linked. You can use `deepcopy` to clone all dimensions of a list:

```
from copy import deepcopy

array1=[[0 for rows in range(9)] for cols in range(9)]
array2=deepcopy(array1)
array1[0][0]=1
print(array2[0][0])
print(id(array1) is id(array2))
```

Result:

> ```
> 0
> False
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Because the sub-array you're changing isn't a copy.

```
print(id(array1[0]), id(array2[0]))
```

Also, don't use `is` for comparing... practically anything but `None`, `True` and `False`.