# Inconsistent mutability of lists in Python. Is there any particular reason for this inconsistency? Please Explain

Tags: python, list, mutability

```py
a = [10, 23, 56, [78]]
b = list(a)
a[3][0] = 95
a[1] = 34
print(b)
```

Output: `[10, 23, 56, [95]]`

Is there any particular reason why the nested value gets changed from 78 to 95; however, the value at the index value = 1 remains 23 only?

Edit explaining my question better:

I've received comments explaining that when I do `new_list = old_list`, changes made in any list will be seen in both the variables. But what I don't understand in this particular case is that why is only one value changing i.e. 95, but not the other value i.e. 23.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment. How do I clone or copy it to prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)

Comment: I think when you use `b=list(a)`, `list` copies all elements to `a`, but the last item is list too, so `list` copies the item by link (ref).

Comment: You made a shallow copy when it sounds like you wanted a deep copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying nested lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541865/copying-nested-lists-in-python)