Loop changes list that it should not
I'm writing weights mutator for my neural network. "distribute_genome" function should slightly mutate best genome and return it.
import random
best_genome = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
def distribute_genome():
    unique_genom = best_genome
    print(best_genome)
    for i in range(len(unique_genom)):
        for j in range(len(unique_genom[i])):
            unique_genom[i][j] += random.randint(-2, 2) #mutation
    print(best_genome)
    print("does not work" if unique_genom == best_genome else "ok")
    return unique_genom
print(distribute_genome())

I noticed that best_genome being changed when function runs. Soon I discovered that this loop changes it, if I delete the loop best_genome will stay the same.
for i in range(len(unique_genom)):
    for j in range(len(unique_genom[i])):
        unique_genom[i][j] += random.randint(-2, 2) #mutation

I found out the reason of this error, and a question with the same problem but it still gives the same result, like here:
import random
best_genome = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
def distribute_genome():
    unique_genom = list(best_genome)
    for i in range(len(unique_genom)):
        for j in range(len(unique_genom[i])):
            unique_genom[i][j] += random.randint(-2, 2) #mutation
    return unique_genom

print("does not work" if distribute_genome() == best_genome else "works")


does not work

How should I fix this?

Loop does not even contacts best_genome in any way Yes it does, because unique_genom = best_genome does NOT make a copy of the list.  It only makes another variable name unique_genom that refers to the SAME list object as best_genom.  So when you modify unique_genom, you are also modifying best_genome, because they are the SAME object.

With new_nested_list = list(another_nested_list) only the outside list object changes, the sub-lists are still identical and shared. Look up a concept named deepcopy to create copies of nested lists.

Another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541865/4165552 with exactly the same kind of nested list.
